# Find the fixed field of a Galois subgroup

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I found the following problem during my research. Let $\alpha$ be a 28-th root of unity and let $\rho_{11}$ such that $\rho_{11}(\alpha) = \alpha^{11}$. Since $\gcd(28, 11) = 1$, $\rho_{11}$ is a field homomorphism. How can I find the fixed field of $\rho_{11}$ over $\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$? If I haven't made a mistake that's a 2-degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ so it is enough with finding an element not in $\mathbb{Q}$ fixed by $\rho_{11}$.

I have tried symmetrization using that:
$$ \langle \rho_{11} \rangle = \{ id, \rho_{11}, \rho_9, \rho_{15}, \rho_{25}, \rho_{23} \}$$
where $\rho_k (\alpha) = \alpha^k$. The obvious candidate for a generator of the fixed field is then:
$$ \alpha + \alpha^{11} + \alpha^9 + \alpha^{15} + \alpha^{25} + \alpha^{23} = 0$$
but since it is null, that's a dead end road.

No power of $\alpha$ is preserved by $\rho_{11}$, so the generator must be something more complicated. I guess I could try to find which element of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is left fixed by just brute force, but since I have to raise it to the power of $11$, that will be very messy.

Since this is the first example I have found that I couldn't attack with these techniques I would be very grateful if answers (or hints) included reasonably general strategies, so I can make my toolbox a bit bigger. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you look separately at the effect of the automorphism on $\alpha^7=i$ and $\alpha^4=\beta$ say. Obviously one checks $i$ first; it isn't fixed.  I think that $\beta+\beta^4+\beta^5$ is fixed, and I think that it is quadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$. [Ps I think your notation is crazy for working with groups: $\rho_{11}$ and so on would be much clearer. ]

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are right about notation, I changed it. However, I don't think $\beta + \beta^4 + \beta^5$ is fixed, I get that the image is $\beta^4 + \beta^2 + \beta^6$, which don't coincide.

Comment: I think I made a mistake: is it $\beta+\beta^4+\beta^2$? I think $\rho$ carries $\beta\mapsto\beta^4\mapsto\beta^2\mapsto\beta$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, that's it! Just out of curiosity, how would you find the degree of the extension? In this case, you can guess is two since it is a non real number, but in a more general case?

Comment: I would look at  the sum of the other three $7$-th roots of unity $\beta^{-1}+\beta^{-4}+\beta^{-2}$. Checkout that they are roots of a quadratic $X^2+X+2$. I think "resolvents" is the magic word.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am sorry, but I am getting lost. I have found the minimal polynomial of an element before, but usually by pure algebraic manipulation, until you find an algebraic relationship between its powers. How would you do that in this case? I have checked that both $\beta + \beta^2 + \beta^4$ and $\beta^{-1} + \beta^{-2} + \beta^{-4}$ are conjugates of $X^2 + X + 2$. What how can I go about finding the polynomial in first place?

Comment: $\beta$ is a primitive $7th$ root of unity. So $(\beta+\beta^2+\beta^4)+(\beta^{-1}+\beta^{-2}+\beta^{-4})=-1$ (since they add to the sum of all roots of $X^7-1$ except the root $1$; and $(\beta+\beta^2+\beta^4)\cdot(\beta^{-1}+\beta^{-2}+\beta^{-4})=3+\beta+\beta^2+\beta^4+\beta^{-1}+\beta^{-2}+\beta^{-4}=3-1=2$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician OK, I feel stupid now. Thank you for your help and your clear explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Let $K_n/\Bbb Q$ be the cyclotomic extension defined by $x^n-1$. It is a standard fact that $\operatorname{Gal}(K_n/\Bbb Q) \cong (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$

By Galois theory, $[(K_{28})^{\rho_{11}} : \Bbb Q] = [(\Bbb Z/28\Bbb Z)^\times : \langle \rho_{11} \rangle] = [12:6] = 2$, so it is a quadratic extension.

To further determine the structure, note that $K_{28} = K_4 K_7$ since $\gcd(4,7)=1$, and Galois groups interact well with compositum of field extensions.

$\rho_{11}$ restricts to $\rho_3$ on $K_4$ since $11 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, and to $\rho_4$ on $K_7$ since $11 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$.

Now $\rho_3$ generates $(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)^\times$ and $\rho_4$ generates an index-2 subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Now it is a standard fact that the quadratic subfield of $K_p$ is $\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2} p} \right)$ for a prime $p$, with the relevant equation being:
$$\pm \sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2} p} = \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \zeta^a$$

Therefore, $(K_{28})^{\rho_{11}} = (K_4)^{\rho_3} (K_7)^{\rho_4} = \Bbb Q (\sqrt{-7})$, with:
$$\pm \sqrt{-7} = \zeta_{28}^4 + \zeta_{28}^8 - \zeta_{28}^{12} + \zeta_{28}^{16} - \zeta_{28}^{20} - \zeta_{28}^{24}$$

Comment: I don't know any of these facts. Do you have any reference about the cyclotomic group?

Comment: See e.g. Ch.2 of [Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1934-7) by Lawrence C. Washington. The statement about Galois group is Theorem 2.5, from which the statement about compositum follows. The quadratic subfield is unique because $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic. The explicit equation for the quadratic subfield is an application of the theory of Gauss sums.